# can we deploy the data service created by wso2 dss, in a separate tomcat or jboss server without using its in built server

Tags: tomcat, jboss, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

can we deploy the data service created by wso2 dss, in a separate tomcat or jboss server without using its in built server(wso2server), if can what are the basic steps need to be followed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Data service created by WSO2 DSS are special kind of artifacts. Although it deploys in axis2 as a web service, WSO2 has written a special deployer to do that. Because of that, Tomcat or Jboss is not capable of identifying data services or deploying them.